# ETL:parallel lookup in and insert in scala

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing, etl

For our ETL, the fact data don't have item_key, but have item_number. During the loading, if we can find the item_key for the item_number, then just use it,if can NOT find, then auto create an item_key. Currently the process is not in parallel, I am thinking about run it in parallel using scala since scala have build-in concurrent collection.

Use a simple example:

```
val keys=1 to 1000
val items=keys map {num=>"Item"+num}
var itemMap=(items zip keys).toMap
```

and now we have millions rows to load whose item number is:

```
def g(v:String)=List.fill(5000)(v)
var fact="Item2000" :: List(items.flatMap(x=>g(x)))
```

Since the fact data has an item item2000 which can't be found in item master data of itemMap, we need to autocreate a map of (item2000,2000) and add it to itemMap so that if in future we find item2000 again we could use the same item key.

How to implement using concurrent collection? For each loop of the row in fact data, if can't find the item key then autocreate, so we need a way to lock itemMap otherwise there might be multiple thead trying to insert autocreate data into itemMap